# Implement a WYSIWYG document editor in WPF?

Tags: wpf, wysiwyg

How will you approach to implement a WYSIWYG document editor in WPF?

This editor is going to be very similar to WYSIWYG html editors, but
back-end data structures do not have to be html. Currently, I have a working version based on mshtml control implemented in c++ (this is pretty much like MS InfoPath). I'm seeking to take out the mshtml dependency from this tool, so using WPF WebBrowser control is a choice I want to avoid.

Basic features to support:

1. Flow style document
2. Supports a basic set of controls (TextBox, DropDown, ListBox, DatePicker, etc)
3. Supports basic styles
4. Supports tables (resize, merge cells, split cells, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not exactly what you are after, but you might like to investigate the FlowDocument support build into WPF as it supports a lot of what you are asking for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/flow-document-overview